# Change xslCompiledTransform output encoding while transformig

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, encoding

I am Converting my XML to XSLT by using xslCompiledTransform and when it transforms it changes the output result encoding which is UTF-16 (by default) 
and when I try to change its or encoding it prompts the error that this property is read-only you can't change it!

I also try xmlWriter and xmlWriterSettings and memory Stream and other solutions but nothing works for me and for the reference I am adding code snippet

```
public static StringBuilder TransformXml(ProcessorConfigElement configSettings, StringBuilder xml, ILog logger)
{
//Perform transformation...
StringBuilder newXmlBuilder = new StringBuilder(xml.Length);
XslCompiledTransform requiredXslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
requiredXslt.Load(configSettings.XsltPath, XsltSettings.TrustedXslt, new XmlUrlResolver());

// I tried this trick also but all in vain 
// Encoding wind1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252);
// XmlWriterSettings xmlSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
// xmlSettings.Encoding = wind1252;
// xmlSettings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
// xmlSettings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
// XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(newXmlBuilder, xmlSettings);

StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
using (TextWriter newXmlWriter = StringWriter.Create(newXmlBuilder))
{

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(configSettings.Delimiter))
{
XsltArgumentList argsList = new XsltArgumentList();
argsList.AddParam("delimiter", "", configSettings.Delimiter);
// here is the actual problem when it transforms its create a mess and converting pound symbol and other symbols as diamond special character (encoding issue.) 
requiredXslt.Transform(GetElement(xml.ToString()), argsList, newXmlWriter);

}
else
{
requiredXslt.Transform(GetElement(xml.ToString()), null, newXmlWriter);

}
}
logger.Info("XSLT applied successfully");

//replace string after transformation to validate and write to file
xml = newXmlBuilder;
return xml;
}
```

I want to use the desired UTF encoding while transforming it to XSLT, anyone?

Comment: It is not clear whether you encounter a problem of XslCompiledTransform outputting the wrong encoding in the XML declaration based on your XSLT code or your expectations or whether you somehow use a particular encoding but later when you try to use the result you perhaps don't have the right code to read the output with that encoding. Where do you have the "mess", which code or application uses the result of the XSLT transformation and wrongly displays the result? Does XSLT output an XML declaration with an encoding information?

Comment: Hi, Actually the problem was that the pound signs changes to special characters when XslCompiledTransform transforms it from given xml file and this problem actually due to the encoding of XslCompiledTransform output Settings as my desired encoding was **Windows-1252** and XslCompiledTransform output default encoding is **UTF-16** and when the file transforms it create a mess and when I try to change the default encoding of XslCompiledTransform output settings it didn't let me do it as it says that the Property is **Read-Only**.

Comment: Any how I figured it out by passing desired **encoding** type in my xslt file at **xsl out** tag. as in documentation it is written that the  XslCompiledTransform output settings pick the encoding from XSLT => xsl out tag if you not provide it then it will be **UTF-16** by default as it is C# internal default encoding for strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Martin Honnen already pointed out, if XSLT already has output declaration along the following line:

> XSLT

```
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" encoding="utf-8"/>
```

Here is c# that picks it up from the XSLT file via **xslt.OutputSettings** parameter:

> c#

```
void Main()
{
    const string SOURCEXMLFILE = @"e:\Temp\UniversalShipment.xml";
    const string stylesheet = @"e:\Temp\UniversalShipment.xslt";
    const string OUTPUTXMLFILE = @"e:\temp\UniversalShipment_output.xml";
    bool paramXSLT = false;


    XslCompiledTransform xslt = new XslCompiledTransform();
    xslt.Load(stylesheet, XsltSettings.TrustedXslt, new XmlUrlResolver());

    // Load the file to transform.
    XPathDocument doc = new XPathDocument(SOURCEXMLFILE);

    XsltArgumentList xslArg = new XsltArgumentList();
    if (paramXSLT)
    {
        // Create a parameter which represents the current date and time.
        DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
        xslArg.AddParam("date", "", d.ToString());
    }

    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(OUTPUTXMLFILE, xslt.OutputSettings))
    {
        xslt.Transform(doc, xslArg, writer);
    }
}
```